# Trouble tapping on link in mobile view of site?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mobile

Just started working on `mobile responsive design` for a site I'm working on. During testing I noticed the `main tabs` that link to different views of the site, which can normally can be clicked with no problem on desktop, barely responds when tapped on a phone or in the browser developer tools that simulate a tap. If I click it repeatedly then it will eventually register, but it's not exactly user friendly.

You can see what I'm talking about if you go to **www.runnercalculator.com** and click between the two tabs on the normal desktop view and then inspect and tap it in mobile.

What is different between a tap and a click that I'm not accounting for here?

How can I make a view link work as a "one tap click" for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making use of **angular-touch.js**(`ngTouch` module) you need to make sure that `ng-click` is placed properly in template.

```
<a href="#/pace" class="tabTabs ng-isolate-scope" info="paceCalc">
   <li class="tabRowLi" ng-click="toggleSelect0()" ng-class="tabRowLi">
       <span class="tabText ng-binding">Running Pace</span>
   </li>
</a>
```

In your template, `ng-click` is placed inside a anchor tag. `ngTouch` module stops event propagation when you click on `<a>` which makes `ng-click` passive.

Avoid using `ngTouch` module unless you have plugins which has dependency over it or take extra care while creating templates with `ng` directives.